# JSON.stringify object with keys without the quotes in subobject

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

My current object looks like this:

```
var file_data = ({
            "file_name_as_key":{
                "id":"file_name_as_id",
                "title":"file title",
                "type":"extention type",
                "cat":"category title",
                "cost":"",
                "desc":"Some text that will go here \"Something in quotes\" <strong>Something as bold</strong> some more text.",
                "img":"image url",
                "url":"Coresponding page url ",
                "status":"Updated"
            }
        });
```

and what I need to have is the following:

```
var file_data = ({
            "file_name_as_key":{
                id:"file_name_as_id",
                title:"file title",
                type:"extention type",
                cat:"category title",
                cost:0,
                desc:"Some text that will go here \"Something in quotes\" <strong>Something as bold</strong> some more text.",
                img:"image url",
                url:"Coresponding page url ",
                status:"Updated"
            }
        });
```

I create the object in my `Code.gs` file then pass the object to the template as `JSON.stringify(my_obj)`.

here is my script:

```
    var file_data = {};

var i = 0;
fileData.forEach(function (row) {
  i++;
  if(i >= 2){
    file_data[row[8]] = {
        id: row[8],
        title: row[0],
        type: row[1],
        cat: row[2],
        cost: row[3],
        desc: row[4],
        img: row[5],
        url: row[6],
        status: row[7]
    }
  }
});

return JSON.stringify(file_data);
```

Can anyone suggest how to go about it so that I can get the object in the desired format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your "desired format" is not JSON. JSON requires quotes around property names. What is the actual goal of the desired non-JSON syntax?

Comment: What do you believe the difference is between the two formats you posted?

Comment: May i know why you wanna do this ? it doesen't make any difference

Comment: The reason for this is that it will be easier to grub each of the elements with $.each() at a later stage I think?

Comment: @AlexB - no; there is zero difference in implementation between JS objects where you specified the keys with quotes or without. Except as Pointy, er, points out, the latter is invalid JSON.

Comment: @Utkanos, OK I understand. Out of curiosity, how do I go about creating the object that I need?

Comment: Well since the quotes vs. non-quotes thing is pertinent only at the point of *manually creating* the object, you would have to make it manually. Any time you inspect an object later - whether you made it manually, or decoded from JSON - it will have quotes around the keys.

Comment: @TheMaster, i have posted my client side code and also described the proble, but the suggestion was that it would not matter wether there are quotes or there are not, it will work the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually what I needed was easily achievable. All I had to do is to add replace to my return statement in the function

```
return JSON.stringify(file_data).replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:');
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to get it saved like:

```
[{}, {}]
```

But not:

```
({}, {})
```

So, after you create the object, push them to an array:

```
file_data.push(fileData)
```

Now, you can iterate through `file_data` array whenever you want.

Comment: the `.push()` does not work in  `Code.gs` because `fileData` is an array `[[],[],[]]`

Comment: fileData should be object not an array.